# Problem with ~\.bashrc - Have to run `bind -x '"\C-l": clear'` each time I start Terminal

Tags: bashrc

I recently made some edits to my `~/.bashrc` file in my Ubuntu 18.03 VM. Apparently I messed them up somehow because now whenever I start Terminal pressing Control + L to clear the screen does not work. [I found a workaround by using this command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141228/control-l-not-clearing-screen): `bind -x '"\C-l": clear'`

However, obviously I'd like to fix the underlying cause of the issue instead of just issuing a command as a symptomatic fix every time. How could I do that - i.e. **what .bashrc statements could break/change Ctrl + L?**

Alternatively I can simply restore my `.bak` version of `~./bashrc`, but for my own edification I would really like to know where I went wrong with this.

Comment: With so little information to go on, all I can suggest is that you do a `diff` between the current file and the backup (or between the current and `/etc/skel/.bashrc`) to narrow it down

Comment: Thank you, @steeldriver. I will do so and update the post.

Comment: `~\.bashrc`? Surely you mean `~/.bashrc`... Or is this on windows?

Comment: You could temporarily insert `set -x` at the beginning of your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant `~/.bashrc` - pesky Windows SysAdmin habits :p